# How to make an assert for required field messages?

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js

How do I make an assert for this required field message?

**Required field message**

[image]

I don't think css selectors will work on this, because this message comes from the browser itself, isn't it? Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does come from the browser, so you probably don't want to test it that way.

If you want to be able to run your automation on a variety of platforms you might instead assert the presence of the attribute 'required' on that field.

```
.useCss().assert.elementPresent("input[required]")
```